# Bigtable NewClient - Global or per request?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

For a Go API that uses Bigtable during each request, should [`NewClient`](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/go/reference#NewClient) be called once when the app starts and the same client be used for each request, or should `NewClient` be called for each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I am the product manager of Google Cloud Bigtable.*

You should reuse the client, because creating a new client is expensive (e.g., to set up authentication), and should **not** be recreated for each request.

We'll update the documentation to be more clear on this topic.